# SQL - Find Highest Single Day of Sales From Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am using **MySQL**..

I have a simple sales table as follow:

```
o----o----------o-----------o
| id | store_id |  logDate  |
o----o----------o-----------o
| 1  |    1     | 2015-1-13 |
| 2  |    1     | 2015-1-14 |
| 3  |    2     | 2015-1-11 |
| 4  |    2     | 2015-1-18 |
o----o----------o-----------o
```

And sale product table

```
o----o----------o---------o------------o
| id | sale_id  |  qty    |    price   |
o----o----------o---------o------------o
| 1  |    1     |       1 |         10 |
| 2  |    2     |       1 |         10 |
| 3  |    2     |       1 |         10 |
| 4  |    3     |       1 |         10 |
| 5  |    3     |       1 |         10 |
| 6  |    3     |       1 |         10 |
| 7  |    4     |       1 |         10 |
| 8  |    4     |       1 |         10 |
o----o----------o---------o------------o
```

Expected Result

```
o-- --------o----------------o---------------------o
| store_id  | SUM(price*qty) |  Highest Date On    | 
o-----------o----------------o---------------------o
|     1     |             20 |           2015-1-14 |
|     2     |             30 |           2015-1-11 |
O-----------o----------------o---------------------o
```

How to achieve my expected result?
I have tried as follow but it didn't work as expected:

```
SELECT store_id, MAX(total), highestSingleDateOn 
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(price * qty) AS total, 
      DATE(s.logDate) AS highestSingleDateOn, s.store_id AS store_id
   FROM sale_product sp JOIN sales s ON s.id = sp.sales_id
   GROUP BY DATE(s.logDate), s.store_id
   ORDER BY DATE(s.logDate) ASC
) AS result_for_highest_single_day
GROUP BY highestSingleDateOn, store_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT store_id, MAX(total), highestSingleDateOn 
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(price * qty) AS total, 
      DATE(s.logDate) AS highestSingleDateOn, s.store_id AS store_id
   FROM sale_product sp JOIN sales s ON s.id = sp.sales_id
   GROUP BY DATE(s.logDate), s.store_id
   ORDER BY total DESC
) AS result_for_highest_single_day
GROUP BY  store_id
```

I just have modified the script `ORDER BY DATE(s.logDate) ASC` >> `ORDER BY total DESC` 
and `GROUP BY highestSingleDateOn, store_id`  >> `GROUP BY  store_id`.

*Above sql script,it uses the unstable features about `group by` of MYSQL.

*Then according to Mysql standard,I write a other version sql script.

```
select table1.*
from 
( SELECT SUM(price * qty) AS total, 
      DATE(s.logDate) AS highestSingleDateOn, s.store_id AS store_id
   FROM sale_product sp JOIN sales s ON s.id = sp.sale_id
   GROUP BY DATE(s.logDate), s.store_id) as table1
,
(select tmp.store_id,MAX(tmp.total) as max_total from 
        (SELECT SUM(price * qty) AS total, 
   DATE(s.logDate) AS highestSingleDateOn, s.store_id AS store_id
   FROM sale_product sp JOIN sales s ON s.id = sp.sale_id
   GROUP BY DATE(s.logDate), s.store_id ) as tmp group by tmp.store_id) as table2

where table1.store_id = table2.store_id and table1.total=table2.max_total
```

Comment: This answer uses a (mis)feature of MySQL that permits columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` (the `highestSingleDateOn` column).  MySQL *explicitly* warns against using this feature (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).  There are other approaches to solving the problem that do not rely on *documented* unstable features of the language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thanks for your reminder.I have modified the answer.

Comment: . . Your modified version should use an explicit `join`, rather than an implicit `join` with the condition in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in MySQL is with multiple an aggregations and then a join.  Perhaps an easier way is to use variables:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM (SELECT sd.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = store_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := store_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn 
      FROM (SELECT DATE(s.logDate) AS date, s.store_id, SUM(price * qty) AS total
            FROM sale_product sp JOIN sales s ON s.id = sp.sales_id
            GROUP BY DATE(s.logDate), s.store_id
            ORDER BY s.store_id, total desc
           ) sd cross join
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @s := -1) params
     ) sd
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: would you mind explaining me about the additional `rn` column? I know this is a helper variable, but what's the rationale behind that?

Comment: Also I don't think the query works.. i have tested against real data. It didn't work as expected.

Comment: @exodream . . . The original answer returned the first day of sales.  I must've misread the question.  You get the highest sale by changing the `order by` clause.